# How to reorder data with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reorder from raw data to a report form but I don't know how to do it. Below is my sample.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Customer Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
     'ID_NO': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'],
     'Account Number': ['123456', '123457', '234567', '345678', '345679', '345680'],
     'Limit': [1000, 1000, 900, 1200, 1200, 1200], 
     'Balance': [400, 600, 800, 300, 400, 200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

But I need something as below:

```
d2 = {'Customer Name': ['A', '123456', '123457', 'B', '234567', 'C', '345678', '345679', '345680'], 
     'ID_NO': ['AA', '', '', 'BB', '', 'CC', '', '', ''],
     'Limit': [1000, '', '', 900, '', 1200, '', '', ''], 
     'Balance': [1000, 600, 400, 800, 800, 900, 300, 400, 200]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2
```

[image]

What should I do in this case. I appreciate all the suggestions and help.

One more question that if I have two Limit number for one customer as below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Customer Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
     'ID_NO': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'],
     'Limit Number': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCD'],
     'Account Number': ['123456', '123457', '234567', '345678', '345679', '345680'],
     'Limit': [1000, 1000, 900, 1200, 1200, 1500], 
     'Balance': [400, 600, 800, 300, 400, 600]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

If I used this below code:

```
out = (pd.concat([df.reset_index()
                    .groupby(['Customer Name','ID_NO', 'Limit Number'], as_index=False)
                    .agg({'Balance':'sum','Limit':'first','index':'first'})
                    .set_index('index'), 
                 df[['Account Number','Balance']]
                      .rename(columns={'Account Number':'Customer Name'})])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         [['Customer Name','ID_NO','Limit','Balance']])
out
```

I will get below result:

[image]

Below is my expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and pass first DataFrame created by remove repeated values by `Customer Name` and `ID_NO` with delete `Account Number` column with set `Balance` to `sum` per both columns, then second by seelct necessary columns with `rename` and last use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

*Requirement is default index*.

```
#if necessary
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
out = (pd.concat([df.drop_duplicates(['Customer Name','ID_NO'])
                    .drop('Account Number', axis=1)
                    .assign(Balance=df.groupby(['Customer Name','ID_NO'])['Balance']
                    .transform('sum')), 
       df[['Account Number','Balance']]
                    .rename(columns={'Account Number':'Customer Name'})])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True))
print (out)
  Customer Name ID_NO   Limit  Balance
0             A    AA  1000.0     1000
1        123456   NaN     NaN      400
2        123457   NaN     NaN      600
3             B    BB   900.0      800
4        234567   NaN     NaN      800
5             C    CC  1200.0      900
6        345678   NaN     NaN      300
7        345679   NaN     NaN      400
8        345680   NaN     NaN      200
```

Or you can use aggreagtion by `sum` and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), only necessary avoid original index in first `DataFrame`, so used `reset_index` with `set_index` trick:

*Requirement is default index*.

```
#if necessary
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
out = (pd.concat([df.reset_index()
                    .groupby(['Customer Name','ID_NO'], as_index=False)
                    .agg({'Balance':'sum','Limit':'first','index':'first'})
                    .set_index('index'), 
                 df[['Account Number','Balance']]
                      .rename(columns={'Account Number':'Customer Name'})])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         [['Customer Name','ID_NO','Limit','Balance']])
print (out)
  Customer Name ID_NO   Limit  Balance
0             A    AA  1000.0     1000
1        123456   NaN     NaN      400
2        123457   NaN     NaN      600
3             B    BB   900.0      800
4        234567   NaN     NaN      800
5             C    CC  1200.0      900
6        345678   NaN     NaN      300
7        345679   NaN     NaN      400
8        345680   NaN     NaN      200
```

EDIT: For sum `unique` values of `Limit` column use custom function:

```
out = (pd.concat([df.reset_index()
                    .groupby(['Customer Name','ID_NO'], as_index=False)
                    .agg({'Balance':'sum',
                          'Limit':lambda x: x.unique().sum(),
                          'index':'first'})
                    .set_index('index'), 
                 df[['Account Number','Balance']]
                      .rename(columns={'Account Number':'Customer Name'})])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         [['Customer Name','ID_NO','Limit','Balance']])

print (out)
  Customer Name ID_NO   Limit  Balance
0             A    AA  1000.0     1000
1        123456   NaN     NaN      400
2        123457   NaN     NaN      600
3             B    BB   900.0      800
4        234567   NaN     NaN      800
5             C    CC  2700.0     1300
6        345678   NaN     NaN      300
7        345679   NaN     NaN      400
8        345680   NaN     NaN      600
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Real master of pandas.

Comment: I forgot one case that I have two Limit Number for one customer. Should I post new question or revise my old one?

Comment: @hoatran - I think revise is OK for me.

Comment: @hoatran - maybe need change `df.drop_duplicates(['Customer Name','ID_NO'])` to `df.drop_duplicates(['Customer Name','ID_NO', 'Limit'])` only.

Comment: @hoatran - output is `2500` ? Not `1200+1500=2700` ?

Comment: Sorry I edited it. It should be 2700.

Comment: I don't know how to express my gratitude. Thank you very very much.